# AttributeError: type object 'SettingsFrame' has no attribute 'ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am on windows - anaconda environment, and I have just updated scrapy 2.4.1 to the latest version 2.5.1, but I am receiving the following error when using any scrapy commands.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\response.py", line 14, in <module>
    from twisted.web import http
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\http.py", line 183, in <module>
    from twisted.web._http2 import H2Connection
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\_http2.py", line 27, in <module>
    import h2.connection
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2\connection.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .events import (
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2\events.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .settings import ChangedSetting, _setting_code_from_int
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2\settings.py", line 25, in <module>
    class SettingCodes(enum.IntEnum):
  File "C:\Users\Data\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2\settings.py", line 60, in SettingCodes
    ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL = SettingsFrame.ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL
AttributeError: type object 'SettingsFrame' has no attribute 'ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL'
```

I attempted to update the h2 package by "conda install -c conda-forge h2", however all requested packages are already installed. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Try following commands:-

```
pip uninstall h2
pip install h2==3.2.0
```

It should work.
`Scrapy 2.5.1` requires `3.x` series of `h2` package.